# Nginx настройка 404 ошибки

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-404, nginx-faq

Сразу скажу что с настройкой сервера знаком поверхностно, возможно, проблема пустяковая. Но буду крайне признателен за помощь. Достался сайт на допилку дизайна и небольшую доработку. На сервере используется связка nginx и php-fpm. Ситуация (простите за оформление, репутации на ссылки не хватило):

```
 - при переходе по ссылке http://blabla.ru/blublu.php - уходит на
   http://blabla.ru/404.php
 - при переходе по ссылке http://blabla.ru/blublu.pdf - ничего не
   происходит и отображается главная http://blabla.ru, хотя в адресной
   строке http://blabla.ru/blublu.pdf
 - при переходе по ссылке http://blabla.ru/asfasflkjw1312kl (т.е. вбитый
   абсолютный бред) - ничего не происходит и отображается главная 
   http://blabla.ru, хотя в адресной строке http://blabla.ru/asfasflkjw1312kl
```

Как я понимаю при запросе любой не существующей ссылки, будь то ссылка на файл или на абсолютный бред, должна быть либо переадреcсация на 404.php. Но этого не происходит. Как исправить? Настройки nginx прикладываю. Заранее спасибо за ответ.

```
user www-data;
worker_processes  4;

timer_resolution 100ms;
worker_rlimit_nofile 8192;
worker_priority -5; #Увеличитвваем приоритет

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {

    server_tokens off;
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65000;
    tcp_nodelay        on;
    client_max_body_size 50m;

    gzip        on;
    gzip_min_length     1100;
    gzip_disable        "msie6";  #Быстрее, но работает только на новых версиях nginx
    #gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";
    gzip_proxied        any;
    gzip_comp_level     4;
    gzip_types          text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml $
    gzip_vary           on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Файл конфигурации из sites-enabled:

```
 server {
 listen 80;
 server_name www.blabla.ru;
 return 301 http://blabla.ru$request_uri;
 }

server {
 listen 80;
 server_name XXX.XX.XXX.X;
 return 301 http://blabla.ru$request_uri;
 }


server {
 listen 80;
 server_name blabla.ru;
 #return 301 $scheme://blabla.ru$request_uri; 
 server_name xxx.xx.xxx.x;
 root /home/hosting/blabla.ru/www/;
 index index.php index.htm index.html;
 error_page 404 /404.php;
 #error_page 403 404;
 access_log /home/hosting/blabla.ru/log/nginx/access.log;
 error_log /home/hosting/blabla.ru/log/nginx/error.log;

location / {
 if (!-e $request_filename){
 rewrite ^/(.*) /index.php?$query_string; #301 redirect
 }
 }

location /r {
 rewrite ^/r/(.*) /r.php?rub=$1; #301 redirect
 }

location /category {
 rewrite ^/category/(.*) /category.php?rub=$1; #301 redirect
 }

location /article {
 rewrite ^/article/(.*) /article.php?rub=$1; #301 redirect
 }
location /pages {
 rewrite ^/pages/(.*) /pages.php?rub=$1; #301 redirect
 }

location /author {
 rewrite ^/author/(.*) /author.php?rub=$1; #301 redirect
 }

location /user {
 rewrite ^/user/(.*) /user.php?rub=$1; #301 redirect
 }

location /register {
 rewrite ^/register/(.*) /register.php?rub=$1; #301 redirect
 }

location /main {
 rewrite ^/main/(.*) /main.php?rub=$1; #301 redirect
 }

location /profile {
 rewrite ^/profile/(.*) /profile.php?rub=$1; #301 redirect
 }

location /logout {
 rewrite ^/logout/(.*) /logout.php; #301 redirect
 }



location ~* ^.+.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
 access_log        off;
 expires           max;
 }
location ~ \.php$ {
 # fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
 # fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
 fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
 fastcgi_index  index.php;

 fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT    /home/hosting/blabla.ru/www;
 fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /home/hosting/blabla.ru/www$fastcgi_script_name;
 fastcgi_param  PATH_TRANSLATED  /home/hosting/blabla.ru/www$fastcgi_script_name;

 include fastcgi_params;
 fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING     $query_string;
 fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD   $request_method;
 fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE     $content_type;
 fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH   $content_length;
 fastcgi_intercept_errors        on;
 fastcgi_ignore_client_abort     off;
 fastcgi_connect_timeout 60000;
 fastcgi_send_timeout 180000;
 fastcgi_read_timeout 180000;
 fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
 fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
 fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
 fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
 }

location = /favicon.ico {
 log_not_found off;
 access_log off;
 }

location = /robots.txt {
 allow all;
 log_not_found off;
 access_log off;
 }

location ~ /\.ht {
 deny  all;
 }

 location /phpmyadmin {

 #auth_basic "Enter Super Secret password!";
 #auth_basic_user_file /home/hosting/.htpasswd;

 root /usr/share/;
 index index.php index.html index.htm;
 location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
 try_files $uri =404;
 root /usr/share/;
 # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
 fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
 fastcgi_index index.php;
 fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
 fastcgi_connect_timeout 60000;
 fastcgi_send_timeout 180000;
 fastcgi_read_timeout 180000;

 include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
 }
 location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
 root /usr/share/;
 }
 }
 location /phpMyAdmin {
 rewrite ^/* /phpmyadmin last;
 }
 }
```

Comment: Зачем вы делаете rewrite на файл php, чтобы потом передать запрос модулю fastcgi?

Почему бы не вызвать нужный обработчик сразу?

Comment: Такая настройка мне досталась от тех кто делал сайт. Я не спец по nginx, поэтому не могу сказать, почему именно так. Посоветуете как переписать код? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вот этот блок «срабатывает» на запросы `/blublu.pdf` (как я понимаю, такого файла в корне сайта нет) и `/asfasflkjw1312kl`, переводя запрос в обращение к `/index.php`:

```
location / {
 if (!-e $request_filename){
 rewrite ^/(.*) /index.php?$query_string; #301 redirect
 }
}
```

если вам не требуется такое поведение, просто закомментируйте этот блок.

Comment: Сработало, спасибо большое!